# getting ID of button pressed with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery code that I use for multiple buttons.  I'm trying to get the ID of the button that is pressed, but all I get is 'undefined'.  I have tried both methods below, but both give the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("#btnSearch, #btnDirectorSearch, #btnEditorSearch, #btnViewableSearch").click(function () {

         alert($(this).id);
         alert(this.id);
     });

 });
```

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` seems you're observing result of `alert(this.id);` wrong. It alerts just fine.

Comment: alert($(this).id) can cause an error. Comment it, it should work. this.id is better solution it is a flyweight design pattern.

Comment: "_What am I doing wrong?_" You're not using google.  The answer to your question is easily found by googling "_jquery get id_"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

It can be used to extract the value of any attribute.

In your case, you're after the id attribute:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

It **can also be used to set** an attribute:

```
$(this).attr('id', 'funkyId');
```

Whenever you have a question, your best bet is to go straight to the jQuery documentation (which is excellent).

I was led straight to the above link when I googled "*jquery get id*".

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

Comment: `I have tried both methods below, but both give the same results.` Then the question doesn't deserve answers IMO

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this -

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the id from

**$(document).ready(function () { 

    $("#btnSearch, #btnDirectorSearch, #btnEditorSearch, #btnViewableSearch").click(function () { 

         alert ($(this).attr("id")); 

     }); 

 });**

Answer (score 1):

When the click handler is executing, jQuery has made sure to set `this` to the DOM element that triggered the event. That means that you can use

```
alert(this.id)
```

to access the `id` attribute. This is because the [`id` attribute is exposed like this](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901) — no jQuery involved.

You can also choose to use [jQuery's `attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead:

```
alert($(this).attr("id"))
```

This way you construct a jQuery object from `this`, and then proceed to use the `attr` method on that object. Note, that `$(this)` won't have an `id` attribute.